# Capturing characters for fields which are enabled

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

[The fields in question look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUrY0.png)

Each password character field is chosen randomly and the user is required to enter their corresponding password character in the specific field. For example if my password is swordfish, in the picture above I would be required to enter the letters s, d and s. So far I have an `If` statement for each element which is hardly ideal and only the `input[]` of the xpath changes with each field.

```
     WebElement p1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[3]
    /div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/table/tbody/tr[6]/td/input[1]
        "));
                if (p1.isEnabled()){
                p1.click();
                p1.sendKeys("s");

                }

                WebElement p2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[3]
/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/table/tbody/tr[6]/td/input[2]
        "));
                if (p2.isEnabled()){
                p2.sendKeys("d");

                }

                WebElement p3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[3]
    /div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/table/tbody/tr[6]/td/input[3]
        "));
                if (p3.isEnabled()){
                p3.sendKeys("s");

                }
```

I have a solution in pseudocode but I don't know exactly how to do it in Java.

```
    for i =0;i<10;i++
associate i with a field
    if passworfield is enabled
     set password letter based on xpath
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the xPath you are using, they only differ on the index of the input.

For my suggested approach you would need to have a char array where you hold the password.

So, a possible approach would be to have a loop with an index more or less like this:

```
char[] password = new char[]{'p','a','s','s','w','o','r','d','1'};

for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/table/tbody/tr[6]/td/input[" + (i + 1) + "]"));

    if (elem != null && elem.isEnabled())
        elem.sendKeys(Character.toString(password[i]));
}
```

Just notice that I'm using Character.toString because I'm not sure if sendKeys allows a char instead of a String. If there's any way that's possible I'd recommend you do so.

EDIT:
Another possibility that has been suggested is to get all the elements first (which would improve the performance as you'd not need to force Selenium to analyze the webpage over and over again.. where it would be simplified to (something approximately like):

```
char[] password = new char[]{'p','a','s','s','w','o','r','d','1'};

List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/table/tbody/tr[6]/td/input"));

for (WebElement elem : elements)
{
    if (elem.isEnabled())
        elem.sendKeys(Character.toString(password[elements.indexOf(elem)]));
}
```

Comment: bonus points if you select all the elements at once (with findElements) before the loop.

Comment: This is great. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with Fernando's answer, but here's something that might help too.

```
     String s1 = "0,p,a,s,s,w,o,r,d,1";
     String[] array = s1.split(",");

      for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++){
String xpath = "/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]
    /div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/table/tbody/
tr[6]/td/input[" + i + "]";

WebElement passw = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
    if (passw.isEnabled()){
     passw.sendKeys(array[i]);
}
                        }
```

Comment: This works too, but the other answer seems much simpler. Thanks anyway.